# Problems with VBA Script - Find User who has an excel file open using network share

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the [following](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/find-out-who-has-excel-file-locked-for-editing-with-vba/) VBA function from Ryan Wells to find which user has an Excel open.

```
Function Excel_File_in_use_by(FilePath As String) As String
Dim strTempFile As String
Dim iPos As Integer, iRetVal As Integer
Dim objFSO As Object, objWMIService As Object, objFileSecuritySettings As Object, objSD As Object
iPos = InStrRev(FilePath, "\")
strTempFile = Left(FilePath, iPos - 1) & "\~$" & Mid(FilePath, iPos + 1)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists(strTempFile) Then
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set objFileSecuritySettings = objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strTempFile & "'")
    iRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)
    If iRetVal = 0 Then
        Excel_File_in_use_by = objSD.Owner.Name
    Else
        Excel_File_in_use_by = "unknown"
    End If
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set objFileSecuritySettings = Nothing
    Set objSD = Nothing
Else
    Excel_File_in_use_by = vbNullString
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

The codes works great when I supply the file path and it begins with a mapped network drive, for example `j:\Workbook.xlsx`.  But when the file path is passed in as a network address, for example `\\server1\Workbook.xlsx` I get runtime error '-2147217406 (80041002)'.

This was my test sub and the 2nd statement is giving me the runtime error

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Excel_File_in_use_by("J:\Workbook.xlsx")
    Debug.Print Excel_File_in_use_by("\\server1\Workbook.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Is it possible to use this code or amended it to be able to pass in file path in the network address as sometimes this is required as not all drives will be mapped.